# new line in a multi-line string

Tags: c#, string, multiline

Trying to override a tostring in one of my classes.

```
 return string.Format(@" name = {0}
                         ID = {1}
                         sec nr = {2}
                         acc nr = {3}", string, int, int ,int); // types
```

But the thing is, the result isn't aligned when printed out:

```
name = test
                                   ID = 42
                                   sec nr = 11
                                   acc nr = 55
```

Trying to add  \n just prints it out without formating. Guessing it has something to do with @"" which I'm using for multi-lining.

Would like it to print out :

```
name = test
ID = 42
sec nr = 11
acc nr = 55
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you add spaces in front, it will be printed that way.

I normally do it like this.

```
   return string.Format(
@" name = {0}
 ID = {1}
 sec nr = {2}
 acc nr = {3}", string, int, int ,int); // types
```

Update: Perhaps a prettier alternative:

```
string[] lines = 
{
  " name = {0}",
  " ID = {1}",
  " sec nr = {2}",
  " acc nr = {3}"
};

return string.Format(
         string.Join(Environment.Newline, lines), 
         arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Comment: That works, so it's a solution, but the code looks so ugly without indentation. Can one do this somewhat "better"?

Comment: @Zka: Not really, thats pretty much the best looking you can get it :(

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, it looks better and is quite manageable for my purposes.

Comment: Another alternative is to refactor your constants out of the code and into a resource file. This has the added benefit of easily allowing multiple translations.

Answer (score 6):

The @ before the string switches off standard C# string formatting, try

```
 return string.Format(" name = {0}\n ID = {1} \n sec nr = {2} \n acc nr = {3}", 
                      string, int, int ,int); // types
```

You can't use the @ *and* use \n, \t etc.

**EDIT**

This is - IMHO - as good as it gets

```
 return string.Format("name = {0}\n" + 
                      "ID = {1}\n" + 
                      "sec nr = {2}\n" + 
                      "acc nr = {3}", 
                       string, int, int ,int);
```

Comment: Actually yea, that works but I really need it to be multi-line as there is more information to be added making it a very long line.

Comment: @leppie: Sorry, why not Windows Friendly?

Comment: \n is not the standard newline on Windows. I know some controls wont work unless you get them \n\r.

Comment: @leppie: Thanks, I'm mostly server side, so haven't noticed.

Answer (score 4):

A solution from msdn:

```
// Sample for the Environment.NewLine property
using System;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("NewLine: {0}  first line{0}  second line{0}  third line",
                          Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
/*
This example produces the following results:

NewLine:
  first line
  second line
  third line
*/
```

Comment: Interesting, I'd have never thought of that

Comment: +4 if possible.. For .NET Fiddle or LinqPad this is THE ANSWER.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, value.Select(i => i)
```

where values is collection of strings

Answer (score 0):

No, it's all the spaces you have in there.

Comment: +1 neutralized. What's wrong with this Answer? It's more than a reason rather than a solution i admit however.

Comment: Yeah, should have put a little more effort into this answer. Mea culpa.